# Lambda not working on default scope for mongoid

Tags: scope, mongoid

I created default scope using the following syntax but this doesn't seem to work. It evaluates 5.minutes.ago while loading the app and then uses same evaluated time to query data.

```
default_scope  -> { where(:created_at.gt => 5.minutes.ago) }
```

I'm using mongoid 2.4.3, rails 3.1.3 and ruby 1.9.3-p0.

Any suggestion would be great help to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Mongoid 3.0.0 introduced support for default scopes with lambdas.

Mongoid does not yet support default scopes with lambdas (see the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/797)).